# Ubuntu 14 cannot mount hard drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have a new Dell Inspiron 3847 desktop running Windows 10. It has a 2TB hard drive. I installed Ubuntu 14 on a USB drive and booted from the drive. Everything seems normal except that when I try to look at folders and files on the hard drive, I get a message saying that Ubuntu "Could not mount 'OS'" It also says that "the NTFS partition is in an unsafe state." I completely shut down the computer and rebooted from the USB drive, but got the same error message. Can anyone help? I am new to Ubuntu so please be patient.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off "Auto hibernation(fast-startup)" in windows 10....
Goto control panel->power settings ->choose what the power button does-> Turn off fast startup

Comment: I turned off fast-startup in Windows but it did not help. Next I turned off the sleep and lock options. Hibernate is also off. These changes did not help either. When I try to look at the hard drive in Ubuntu the error message now says "Unable to access 'OS." "Exited with a non-zero exit status 14: Windows is hibernated, refused to mount. The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown Windows fully (no hibernation or fast-starting) or mount the volume read-only..." I must be missing something here. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @JimD. did you reboot into Ubuntu or fully shut down and power back up?

Comment: @Jim Restart windows 10 and boot into ubuntu...

Comment: I fully shut down windows and then powered up the computer, reset the boot sequence to use the USB drive, and went into Ubuntu. The only further step would be to literally unplug the computer before booting into Ubuntu.

Comment: I found the solution. In addition to turning off hibernation under the power options, it was necessary to open a command prompt (admin) and issue the following command:  "powercfg /h off". I found this solution after many searches here on the Ubuntu forum. Thanks very much for the help.